# How do you force a size limit to prevent format truncation?

Tags: c

```
submission.c:112:32: error: '%02d' directive output may be truncated writing between 2 and 3 bytes into a
region of size between 0 and 2 [-Werror=format-truncation=]
 snprintf(strTime, 5, "%02d:%02d", minFormed, secFormed);
                            ^~~~
submission.c:112:26: note: directive argument in the range [-59, 59]     snprintf(strTime, 5, "%02d:%02d", minFormed, secFormed);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
submission.c:112:5: note: 'snprintf' output between 6 and 9 bytes into a destination of size 5
 snprintf(strTime, 5, "%02d:%02d", minFormed, secFormed);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have 2 variables, `minFormed` and `secFormed`, both of which are integers.

Through this, I don't believe either of them could be more than 2 bytes each. The timer format should be "00:00" so that's 5 bytes. How do I force the `secFormed` part to only be 2 bytes?

EDIT: Sorry it was late and forgot to show more code

```
char * getCurrentTime (void) {
    double time = ( overflow_counter * 256.0 + TCNT0 ) * PRESCALE  / FREQ;
    int timePassed = (int)(floor(time));
    int secFormed = timePassed % 60;
    int minFormed = timePassed / 60;
    char strTime[5];
    snprintf(strTime, 5, "%02d:%02d", minFormed, secFormed);
    return strTime;
}
```

The timer should really not exceed 99:59 because it's for a game that can be played in a couple of minutes, so some sort of time limitation could be implemented.

Edit: Error after changing string buffer to a size of 6

```
submission.c:109:32: error: '%02d' directive output may be truncated writing between 2 and 3 bytes into a
region of size between 1 and 3 [-Werror=format-truncation=]
 snprintf(strTime, 6, "%02d:%02d", minFormed, secFormed);
                            ^~~~submission.c:109:26: note: directive argument in the range [-59, 59]     snprintf(strTime, 6, "%02d:%02d", minFormed, secFormed);                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
submission.c:109:5: note: 'snprintf' output between 6 and 9 bytes into a destination of size 6
 snprintf(strTime, 6, "%02d:%02d", minFormed, secFormed);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What is `time` ? Is `0 <= time < 6000` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just ***guessing*** here since you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

It seems you're passing the length `5` as argument for the buffer size. That is the buffer size *including* the string terminator.

From [this `snprintf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> `bufsz`   -   up to `bufsz - 1` characters may be written, plus the null terminator

Your string is *six* characters including the terminator, so you need a buffer of at least six characters and tell `snprintf` that size.

Oh and the note about range is because you use *signed* integers, so the range includes negative numbers as well, which means extra space. You should probably use `unsigned int` instead, and the format `"%02u"`.

Comment: Hi does my edit help you at all? I tried the unsigned int's with the "%02u" format but that still didn't work.

Comment: @OskarSherrah Your format string isn't the problem. Read the answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory I've changed the string length and put the error It gave in the post.

Comment: @OskarSherrah Just make the buffer some reasonable size that will handle all the possibilities, such as 25. There's no reason to try and minimize a small array.